# Is there any way to stream audio and video files from Windows laptop to iPhone 6 plus at anytime with my own wifi hotspot?

Tags: iphone, wifi, streaming, ftp

I have a iPhone 6 plus and a laptop with wifi. I just need to stream audio and video files from Windows Laptop at anytime with my own wifi hotspot.

My workarounds:

- Have tried VLC Streamer but it streams only video and also only in my office wifi.

Please suggest a best and free method to make it done.

Answer (score -1):

Download FileBrowser App from Apple Store you can get the lite version for free and if you are Jailbroken you can get the full version from Appcake and it will solve your problem

Once you have installed the App connect your PC and phone on the same network. App will scan available devices on the network to connect select your PC and then you can browse the files select the one you want to stream and thats it

Comment: Instead of just dropping the name of an app, can you please explain in more detail on how to set things up both on Windows and iPhone side to make streaming from Windows to iPhone work

Comment: Once you have installed the App connect your PC and phone on the same network. App will scan available devices on the network to connect select your PC and then you can browse the files select the one you want to stream and thats it

Comment: Please edit the answer accordingly, comments may get deleted at any time.